# formula works fine with the cell in hh:mm:ss format, but the same formula gives incorrect value in cell with mm:ss format

Tags: excel

my data appears as this

```
WAIT
29:45:00
2:41:14
46:06:00 ' <---
0:25
19:23 ' <---
2:25:12
37:36:00
2:12:24
1:34:35
1:54:13
13:00:53
```

when i am applying the formula =HOUR(F7)*3600+MINUTE(F7)*60+SECOND(F7) to 46:06:00, it gives the correct answer, however when same formula is applied to the 19:23, excel recognizes 19:23 in HHMMSS format, however it is MMSS...
i have a huge data base and it would be very difficult for me to change it manually....
please help...

Comment: yes, i was getting the desired answer

Answer (score 1):

By default, Excel treats numbers in the format xx:xx or x:xx as h:mm, and NEVER as mm:ss.

I don't see a way to transform the values into valid hh:mm:ss, since there is no handle for Excel to determine which number is lacking the hour part.

The best option is to change the routine that writes the data and have the hour entered as 00: before a mm:ss value.

Comment: Try this with 19:23:00 versus 19:23 that is MEANT to be interpreted as 00:19:23 - not the same .

Comment: @pnuts The problem as I see it is that by default Excel interprets 19:23 as hh:mm and no re-formatting will get it to be interpreted as 00:19:23. So, if you paste the Op's sample data into Excel, 19:23 will be hh:mm. The challenge is to find an algorithm to identify where the value is meant to be mm:ss instead of Excel's default hh:mm

Answer (score 1):

As long as the data column is formatted as text, you could test how many colons exist in the string and apply a different calculation depending on whether there is 1 or 2. If there is only 1 colon, then use what Excel thinks is the hours as the minutes, and what Excel thinks are the minutes as the seconds.

`=IF(LEN(F7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F7,":",""))=2,HOUR(F7)*3600+MINUTE(F7)*60+SECOND(F7),HOUR(F7)*60+MINUTE(F7))`

Comment: For `0:25`, my formula gives me the answer 25, which is what I think OP is expecting, namely the length of time expressed in seconds.

Comment: Hey, I've watched you pick up 8000 rep in the time it's taken me to get 100! So there is little sign of idiocy.

Comment: @MattClarke, this could actually be the solution. From wherever the data comes from, copy and paste into Notepad. Then format the complete column A as text. Then copy and paste from Notepad. This will retain the data as text instead of interpreting it as dates.

Comment: teylyn- cant do that as data is merged into 1 column so i have to first perform text to column step...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell whether your data is text-formatted or not - `HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND` functions work just as well on text-formatted times as real times. What result do you get with this formula?

`=ISNUMBER(F7)`

If that gives you FALSE then your "times" are text formatted in which case this formula will give you the total seconds:

`=LOOKUP(999,({"","0:"}&F7)+0)*86400`

format result cell as general

That will interpret `19:23` as 19 minutes 23 seconds as required. For `46:06:00` you will get the result `165960`, the total seconds in 46 hours and 6 minutes. Your formula is giving you just the seconds from the remainder after multiples of 24 hours are removed, as pnuts points out. That's because

`=HOUR("46:06:00")`=**22**

If you want the result to be `79560` then you can add a `MOD` function like this:

`=MOD(LOOKUP(999,({"","0:"}&F7)+0),1)*86400`

The `LOOKUP` function works here because it exploits the fact that concatenating "0:" to the start of `19:23` (and then doing a calculation like +0) converts `19:23` (19 hours 23 minutes) to `0:19:23` (zero hours, 19 minutes, 23 seconds) but concatenating 0: to `46:06:00` and then adding 0 gives you an error.

Answer (score 0):

Guyz, thx for answering the question..
here is what i tried-

first i applied 
=TEXT(D2,"hh:mm:ss") formula to the cell value and then used =IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(("00:"&d2)+0),d2), so 19:23 got changed to 00:19:23..

It worked though i had to do some manual work on the data...